# C# datatable to listview

Tags: c#, listview, datatable

I like to be able to view datatable in windows form

I managed to get the headers only with ListView how to get the data in there

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();

data = EnumServices();

//create headers
foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
{
      listView_Services.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
```

I just want to show now the data in there!

cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
    }
    listView_Services.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**Update:**  also, if you're calling your method more than once, you need to either clear the columns collection before adding the columns, or check to see if the columns have already been added - otherwise, the number of columns will keep increasing every time you call your method.

Comment: I assume that means you have a blank row of data in your database?

Comment: Or do you mean the first *column* is empty?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for solution to this but I failed. I wasn't able to find any that would best answer to this problem, so I made my own solution. I am so much glad that I was able to make this solution as shorter, easier and more understandable yet would best answer to what most of us looking for.

```
    public void ShowCurrentParked()
    {
        dt3 = new DataTable();

        dt3.Clear();    //clear to avoid overlapping data (new DataTable is not enough)

        lstViewShowCurrentParked.Items.Clear();  //clear items to accept new or updated data to avoid overlapping/duplicate data

        dt3 = pBAL.ShowCurrentParked();  //datasource (class)
        for (int j = 0; j < dt3.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            lstViewShowCurrentParked.BeginUpdate();
            lstViewShowCurrentParked.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {dt3.Rows[j][1].ToString(),dt3.Rows[j][2].ToString(),
        dt3.Rows[j][3].ToString()}));
        }

        lstViewShowCurrentParked.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        lstViewShowCurrentParked.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

        lstViewShowCurrentParked.EndUpdate();

        dt3.Clear();   //clear again to avoid overlapping data (new DataTable is not enough) .. to make datatable really empty


        //BeginUpdate and EndUpdate will just lessen the flicker during listview update
    }
```

Efficiency:
1. fast
2. avoid data duplication
3. less flicker

Answer (score 0):

```
   DataTable sample = new DataTable(); //Sample Data
            sample.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            sample.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
            sample.Columns.Add("StartTime", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("EndTime", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("EndDate", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("AllDayEvent", typeof(bool));
            sample.Columns.Add("Body", typeof(string));
listViewContacts.Items.Clear();

foreach (DataRow dr in sample.Rows)
            {
                DataRow row = sample.NewRow();
                row["Subject"] = dr.Subject;
                row["Location"] = dr.Location;
                row["StartTime"] = dr.Start.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                row["EndTime"] = dr.End.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                row["StartDate"] = dr.Start.Date;
                row["EndDate"] = dr.End.Date;
                row["AllDayEvent"] = dr.AllDayEvent;
                row["Body"] = dr.Body;
                sample.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            sample.AcceptChanges();
            foreach (DataRow dr in sample.Rows)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dr["Subject"].ToString());

                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["Location"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["StartTime"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["EndTime"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["StartDate"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["EndDate"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["AllDayEvent"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["Body"].ToString());



                    this.listViewContacts.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarising the above question and answers into a simple copy and paste function, because time is important -

```
 public static void CopyDataTableToListView(DataTable data, ListView lv)
        {
            lv.BeginUpdate();

            // if column count is different (typically not yet populated)
            if (lv.Columns.Count != data.Columns.Count)
            {
                lv.Columns.Clear();

                // prepare columns
                foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                {
                    lv.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
                }
            }

            // clear rows
            lv.Items.Clear();

            // load rows
            foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
                for (int i = 1; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
                }
                lv.Items.Add(item);
            }

            lv.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
            lv.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            lv.EndUpdate();
        }
```