# Splitting a string into 3 different arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am receiving a string reply from serial port and this reply contains 3 different value. Every value is separated with `';'`.
For example;

```
10;155.4587;0.01
```

I need to separate these values and add to a Listview box.

I've found examples of `Split(';')` function but i think it is not possible to assign split values to different arrays.

Is there any way to perform this extraction with using/not using split() function?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you want 3 arrays of 1 element each?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765234/c-sharp-datatable-to-listview

Comment: You should use a `regular expression`. See `Regex`

Comment: @CaptainWibble Yes. I have a Listview object with three columns named TD,AD,CT. from the example reply **10** should be stored into **TD**, **155.4587** should be stored into **AD** column and **0.01** should be stored to the **CT** column.

Comment: Doesn't the Linq Select on a string return an array of chars? The 'x' is not the string, it's an IEnumerable over the original string, each x being the next char? Something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a wide variety of methods to doing this, you could use a [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) to delimit each item and use Lambda functions.

You could do something more basic like manipulating the below drawn-out example:

```
string s = "10;155.4587;0.01";
string[] a = new String[1];
string[] b = new String[1];
string[] c = new String[1];

string[] z = s.Split(';');

for(int i=0; i< z.Length; i++)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
            a[0] = z[i];
            break;
        case 1:
            b[0] = z[i];
            break;
        case 2:
            c[0] = z[i];
            break;

    }
}

Console.WriteLine(a[0] + ' ' + b[0] + ' ' + c[0]);
```

The above illustrates how to manipulate elements but doesn't scale exactly well you may wish to pursue the anonymous route with the first comment using lambdas (see mukesh kudi's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an array of input strings...

```
        string[] a1 = new string[] {
            "10; 155.4587; 0.01",
            "20; 255.4587; 0.02",
            "30; 355.4587; 0.03",
        };

        List<string> r1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> r2 = new List<string>();
        List<string> r3 = new List<string>();

        foreach (string t1 in a1)
        {
            string[] t2 = t1.Split(";");
            r1.Add(t2[0]);
            r2.Add(t2[1]);
            r3.Add(t2[2]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with help of linq...

```
string s = "10;155.4587;0.01";
var arrList = s.Split(';').Select(x => new string[] { x }).ToArray();
```

Here arrList contains three arrays. but i am not sure how this will help you. if you want to bind this result with ListView you have to traverse this collection and get each array value and bind to listview. you can do this with single array by traverse it's index's.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more please? Maybe with some codes?. I am fairly new in C#.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
To add just one list view item use:

```
 var s = "10;155.4587;0.01";
 var values = s.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(values[0]);
 listViewItem.SubItems.Add(values[1]);
 listViewItem.SubItems.Add(values[2]);
 listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

Assuming you have multiple strings to populate the listBox, try:

```
         ListView listView1 = new ListView();
         listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), new Size(300, 200));
         listView1.View = View.Details;
         listView1.GridLines = true;
         listView1.Columns.Add("TD");
         listView1.Columns.Add("AD");
         listView1.Columns.Add("CT", -2);
         var sValues = new string[] { "10;155.4587;0.01", "11;156.4587;0.02", "12;157.4587;0.03" };
         var values = sValues.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                           .Select(x =>
                           {
                              var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(x[0]);
                              listViewItem.SubItems.Add(x[1]);
                              listViewItem.SubItems.Add(x[2]);
                              return listViewItem;
                           });
         listView1.Items.AddRange(values.ToArray());
```

Comment: This is working by the terms of decoding the string but compiler gives an error when i try to pass the string into it. Do you have any idea why? ( i added the related parts of the codes to question)

Comment: @TeoLaferla, I've edited the post to include what you need.

Comment: Now first reply gets decoded and put in into Listview but when the second string comes it throws an expection for values[1] line saying System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Debug the code and check the string that is coming in. it might not have a `;` in it

Comment: @TeoLaferla, what should happen if there is no `;` in the string?

Comment: I am sure it has `;` because i am sending this data package from MCU to PC. In the MCU i am sprintf'ing 3 values separated by `;`. Thus i am sure.

Comment: what was the value of the string variable when the error occured?

Comment: on the first iteration **values[0] = 0**, **values[1] = 20.4587**, **values[2] = 0.01**. On the second iteration **values[0] = 10**, **values[1] = 20** (should be float number as in the first iteration) then when code comes to **values[2]** it crashes so there is no **values[2]** shown. When error happened string value should be **10;20.4578;0.01**.

Comment: string.Split should ideally give results as expected for 10;20.4578;0.01. could you add `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);` as the first line in the `SetText` method and check the output window to see what is the value of `text` variable? Thanks..

Comment: On the first iteration `text` is `60;13.7392;0.01`. On the second iteration `text` is `"60;13.7392;0.0170;13.7396;0.01"`. Two sequential inputs are put together.

Comment: check_data has received = data[0] + data[1];, which is combining multiple values. not sure if this is what you want for your requirement. Consider sending only the last value in the data array to the SetText method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.
With the suggestion of @Captain Wibble, i successfully decoded my replies and add to Listview item.

Here is what i did for anyone in same trouble;
First i added my data packages "\r\n"

> 10;12.2345;0.01\r\n

I used;

> serial.ReadLine()

Function to receive incoming data.
To decode and store the data into a listview object i use;

```
     var s = text;
        string[] a = new String[3];
        //string[] b = new String[1];
        //string[] c = new String[1];

        string[] z = s.Split(';');

        for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    a[0] = z[i];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    a[1] = z[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    a[2] = z[i];
                    break;

            }
        }

        itm = new ListViewItem(a);
        listView5.Items.Add(itm);
```